# how to implement grid over Osmdroid openstreet map in android java

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I am creating an offline map application using osmdroid openstreet map I done maximum work but I am stuck on one task i.e. I want to show grid over on my map and that grid size should change when I zoom the map grid size should increases and when I zoom out the map grid size should decreases and also I want latitude longitude of specific grid.
if any one have any idea about how to achieve what I am asking please let me now it will be a big help for me from senior I am looking forward for my solution

thanks in advance to android developer and other who might now the solution.

Comment: this question is veeery broad, but I can ensure you that this is achievable. try with some custom class, which `extends MapTileProviderBase`, override `getMapTile(final long pMapTileIndex)` and generate your bitmap. you can get X, Y and zoom level from `pMapTileIndex` with methods: `MapTileIndex.getX(pMapTileIndex)`, `MapTileIndex.getY(pMapTileIndex)` and `MapTileIndex.getZoom(pMapTileIndex)`

Comment: Download the OsmDroid demo app from the Google Play Store at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.osmdroid. Go to **More Samples > Data** to see sample demos related to gridlines. The code for the related sample demos can be found at https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/data.

Comment: @snachmsm sir can you show me a code how to done  this approach I am not getting how to implement  this extends  new class

Comment: @snachmsm and I am able to show map on screen but i want show grid over on that map

Comment: even better than my approach you can find in linked repo by @ecle e.g. take a look at [LatLonGridlineOverlay2](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/713f680f8e7c56418331415f7dd8adb9b6f43375/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/gridlines/LatLonGridlineOverlay2.java#L24)